# struts 2 jquery plugin set the form target

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

How is it possible to set the target of an `<sj:submit>` to top.

As an sample login page should open new AFTER the ajax base validations ends:

```
<s:form id="loginForm" action="login-process-result" namespace="/security" >

    <sj:submit button="true" 
        validateFunction="formValidator" validate="true" key="form.btn.login    />
</s:form>
```

I tried `sj:submit targets` and `s:form target`, none of the worked!

I do not want to use `s:submit` as the form validation must be done via Ajax.

Comment: what do you mean by `top` ?

Comment: I mean the target of the form the link, as you now the target could be _balnk,_self,_parent,_top. But I don't know how can I set it here. I found some work around, but hope to find better answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow the struts2 jquery `ajax validation` and `target` concept, I used below solution:

The login-form.jsp (no target is set):

```
<s:form id="loginForm" action="login-process-result" namespace="/security" >
    <sj:submit button="true" 
        validateFunction="formValidator" validate="true" key="form.btn.login    />
</s:form>
```

The action (with validations)

```
  @Action(value = "login-process-result")
  @Validations(requiredStrings={
          @RequiredStringValidator(fieldName="userID",key="validate.required"),
          @RequiredStringValidator(fieldName="password",key="validate.required")} )
  public String result() throws ClientException{

           //Authentication login goes here  
           return SUCCESS;
  }
```

And finally the result form which do the trick, is a normal jsp which changes the window location via javascript

The page shows an success message and make an small delay before changing the url, which is optional and can be removed.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

You have logged in successfully .... 
<br/>
<img src="images/loggin-in-progress.gif" />
<s:url var="url" action="private-page" namespace="/"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function reload() {
        window.location.href = "${url}";
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout('reload()', 800);
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put it on the form, not on the submit tag:

```
<s:form action = "login-process-result" 
     namespace = "/security" 
            id = "loginForm" 
        target = "_top" >
```

But are you sure this is what you want ? [Take a look at how `target="_top"` works](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/_A_TARGET_95y116y111y112y.html).

From your description, I don't think so.

Comment: If I use s:form I lose the struts 2 jquery plugin ajax validation!

Comment: You are ALREADY using s:form in your code. ? And BTW, which are the other options ? (apart from HTML form, that works too) ?

Comment: I made a mistake! I meant "If I use s:form with target="_top" I lose the struts 2 jquery plugin ajax validation!" As you mentioned the target="_top" is working, But when you use it with jQuery Ajax validation the form always targets to _top no matter if the form has valid input or not. I am looking to find if the framework has the build in support to: keep validate the form via ajax and send the form to _top when the action is done successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you require such a behavior.

All I can imagine, is just updating a particular part of a page via Ajax using the struts2 jquery plugin to submit a form & get the response and push it in the DOM.

Here's what you can do :

1. Submit the form via ajax
2. Do validation on the server-side
3. Make the response being returned fill in the desired area of the page.

In order to do this using the Struts2 Jquery Plugin, you can use `onCompleteTopics` & `onErrorTopics` of `sj:submit`

JSP

```
<s:form action="myAction">
<!-- form elements -->
<sj:submit onCompleteTopics="success" onErrorTopics="error"/>
</s:form>
```

Javascript

```
$.subscribe('success',function(event){
    var responseText=event.originalEvent.responseText;
});
```

Above is un-tested code, but I'm sure it explains on how to attend the problem in hand.

Comment: I got the idea you mentioned. By the way I don't know why the onErrorTopics is never published!